# Script output is different between C# Console and PS or CMD

Tags: c#, powershell, process

I am trying to get a list of the installed applications, i have a couple of scripts which do the trick in powershell or from the command window.

but, when i try to run a powerscript command or run a process, i get different data.

the CMD and PowerScript approach gets me 360 applications, but if i run from c# i get 215, and it outputs everything twice ??

simple power script method

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion
```

the call to run a process

```
        process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-executionpolicy unrestricted -File D:\PS-Scripts\InstalledPrograms.ps1";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

am I missing something, why does the process call return different data, and also outputs everything twice.

Thanks

Comment: Is the hosting application compiled for 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: any cpu, prefer 32bit

Comment: ok, so have tried it as 64bit, and it gives the same output as the working methods.  but, i need to be able to run this as a 32bit as it is used on both windows and linux,